# SQL 5.7 group by по максимальному значению

Tags: php, sql

столкнулся с проблемой при переходе MYSQL 5,6 на 5,7 выборка выбирает не корректно

подскажите как правильно создать запрос

к примеру есть таблица

```
id id_user lesson mark
1   100      5     12
2   100      5     11
3   101      5     11
4   102      5     10
```

есть юзер 100 у которого две оценки за урок нам нужно получить одну оценку но последнюю
если сделать

```
select *
from t1
group by id_user
```

то юзер 100 получает оценку 12 а ожидаемый результат 11.

5,6 версия выбирает корректно но 5,7 не так как ожидалось , подскажите как поправить ?

Comment: *5,6 версия выбирает корректно* Это - случайность. Везение, которое в любой момент может кончиться. *получить одну оценку но последнюю* Какой точный критерий "последнести" оценки? максимальный ID?

Comment: да максимальный id

Comment: Тогда в подзапросе получаете макс. ID для студента, и выбираете запись в основном запросе по этому ID.

Comment: надо во всех учебниках первым абзацем раздела "Оператор SELECT" писать, что порядок выборки не определен, покуда не указана инструкция `order by`

Answer (score 0):

помогла статья с подзапросом https://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html 
пример

```
`SELECT t.`user_id`, t.`post`, t.`time`
FROM `test_table` t JOIN
(SELECT `user_id`, max(`time`) as `mtime` FROM `test_table` GROUP BY `user_id`) as t1
ON t.`user_id`= t1.`user_id` AND t.`time` = t1.`mtime`;`
```