# MySQL выбрать максимальное значение для группы и всю строку с этим значеним

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL 5.7
Покажите как правильно сделать выборку из таблицы.
Нужно для каждого студента оставить преподавателя у которого `counter` максимальный

К примеру у меня есть таблица

```
stud   id_prepod  counter
иванов   1111      1
иванов   2222      4
петров   1111      2
```

В результате я хочу видеть иванова с преподавателем 2222 так как у него максимальный `counter` и петрова

```
stud   id_prepod  counter
иванов   2222      4
петров   1111      2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно найти с помощью такого запроса

```
select s1.*
from student s1
left join student s2 on s1.stud=s2.stud and s2.counter>s1.counter
where s2.id_prepod is null
```

Или же вариант с подзапросом, который Вы же и использовали уже ранее в другом вопросе - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026011/sql-5-7-group-by-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E?rq=1)

```
select s1.stud, s1.id_prepod, s1.counter
from student s1
join (select s2.stud,  max(s2.counter) as counter
from student s2 group by s2.stud) s3 
on s1.stud=s3.stud and  s1.counter=s3.counter
```

Тут [фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ab040ce7208e6221a293e31b301b66e2)

Comment: Хороший ответ. +1 с моей стороны.

Answer (score 0):

Препод выбирается первый попавшийся в таблице, удовлетворяющий условию макс(счётчик)

```
SELECT 
   stud AS [Student], 
   First(idp) AS [id_prepod],
   Max(cnt) AS [Counter]
FROM T3
GROUP BY T3.stud;
```